How to use one database for two projects or more in vercel
I have build two project using nextjs and I have already hosted the first one using vercel and now when I tried to host the second one I have found that vercel allow for creation of only one database using free plan.
I'm using prisma and postgres for database and currently don't want to pay for premium plan to host projects that only for showcasting.
What I'v done is that I hosted the second project in vecel using the same database from the first project but the second project didn't work when I'm trying to access the database it cases an error.
the database seems to only have tables from the first project thought?
